# accessing iterator inside .getResultList() query

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

situation is simple.

I have very slow DB so I decided to make progressbar of current select query.
Output is list of all rows from table.

```
transaction.begin();
Query q = em.createQuery('some sql string');
list = q.getResultList();
transaction.commit();
```

I want to increment progressbar after each row gets inserted to list.
Is there any way? 
Thank you

Comment: Where and how you want to show progress bar and to whom?

Comment: it doesnt matter where and how . I just need a single int output from query of current possition . Right now I cant access count (or how many selects passed), I have to wait while hibernate process every single select and after then I get a resultset. I just need to count steps somehow.

Comment: Something is wrong If Hibernate generates many SQL statements for one JPA query. You should chekc if you can work with `@BatchSize`

Comment: I have made some test with @BatchSize, its working way better now. Thx for advice.

Answer (score 0):

I have done some research and I it should be done by org.hibernate.event.* listeners.

Time to study more